# signalling between Java and Perl programme

Tags: java, perl

Is there any way to establish communication between parallelly running Perl and Java program.
If a signal is up , then java program must run and Perl program must sleep . If signal is down java program must sleep and Perl program must awake and run where it resumed earlier   . Please let me know , if these is any possibility to simulate this ??

Comment: exclusive file locks, with or without blocking might be useful

Comment: I have a similar idea. Is there any other way , like , signals , threads , etc??

Comment: how it can be done in sockets or pipes??

Comment: What's the connection between the java and perl processes? Did java spawn the perl process, or was it the other way round, or were both spawned by some other process?

Comment: yeah , java and Perl processes are spawned by another Perl program . How to synchronize 2 spawned processes .

Comment: send SIGSTOP/SIGCONT signals on unix system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals

Comment: What is the operation system? How and where is the "signal" available which decides which process shall run?

Comment: I want a  platform independent solution .